# How to select first list item to null using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

hi i have a drop down list and i'm trying to set the first list item to value null and the text to '---' so when selecting '---' from the drop down list the value will be null so have succeed doing this in the `.aspx` page using Sql data source like this

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqsGetAllJobs" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand=" SELECT Null [JOB_ID], '---' [JOB]
                            UNION
                            SELECT distinct [JOB_ID],[JOB] FROM [TNA].[vu_Position] where [JOB_ID] is not null and [JOB] is not null order by 2"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but i want to do this using linq query and i have try every thing but nothing so please any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this class and data as a mockup of the actual schema / data of your DB:

```
class vu_Position
{
    public int? JOB_ID { get; set; }
    public string JOB { get; set; }
}

List<vu_Position> Positions = new List<vu_Position>
{
    new vu_Position { JOB_ID = null, JOB = "A"},
    new vu_Position { JOB_ID = 1, JOB = "B"},
    new vu_Position { JOB_ID = 2, JOB = "C"},
    new vu_Position { JOB_ID = 3, JOB = null}
};
```

this is a version of a linq query imitating the `SelectCommand` of your `SqlDataSource`:

```
 var selectedJobs = (from j in new List<vu_Position>() 
                               { 
                                 new vu_Position() { JOB_ID = null, JOB = "---" } 
                               }
                     select j)

                     .Union    

                     (from j in Positions
                      where j.JOB_ID != null && j.JOB != null
                      orderby j.JOB
                      select j);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this :

```
List<string> list = new List<string> {"1.5","2.5","3.1","4.2","" };

var a = (
    from aa in list
    select  string.IsNullOrEmpty( aa) ? null : aa
    );
```

hope it helps, if you need more help with creating list items ask me.